# Enable IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2010 for C++ .NET

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, intellisense

I use Visual Studio 2010 Express C++ as my main ide. Now i am writing a .NET application using C++-CLI and i get annoying on the fact that IntelliSense is disabled for C++-CLI. Is possible to enable it? If so, how? Thank you in advice for your answers and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @DavidYaw Excuse me for posting an already answered question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in IntelliSense for C++/CLI in VS 2010. It's not that it's disabled, it simply doesn't exist.

There are two solutions that you can use to get IntelliSense, both of which cost money:

- Upgrade to VS 2012. 2012 has full IntelliSense support for C++/CLI.
- There's an add-on called Visual Assist, from a company called [Whole Tomato](http://www.wholetomato.com/). Among its features, it provides IntelliSense for C++/CLI in VS 2010. (Disclaimer: I have not used Visual Assist personally, though several of my team members did before we upgraded to VS 2012.)